# Handling fetched objects in React components

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm a React novice, learning on FCC, and I'm tearing my hair out trying to work with a fetched object.
I'm trying to build a basic 'Random Quote Machine' React component which fetches (and then renders values from) an object. The object (fetched in **componentDidMount**) has a single key (**quotes**) which is an array of objects (each of which has **quote** and **author** keys), and I assign this array to local state (**quotesData**) and then as a constant in the **render**.
Essentially, the component should display a random quote on first **render** and then again each time the New Quote **button** is clicked. So, I assign (at random) one of the objects in the array to **nextQuote**.
It's after this that I run into problems. I can **console.log(quotesData)** (and **nextQuote**) without issue, but why can I not then assign values from the object stored in **nextQuote** to **nextQuoteQuote** or **nextQuoteAuthor**, using dot (or bracket) notation?
Here's a link to the pen (the full code of which is also below): https://codepen.io/igorgetmeabrain/pen/rNmwMEM

Right now, it just keeps throwing object errors at me and won't render at all. Please help!

```
class RandomQuotes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isFetching: false,
      quotesData: [],
      random: Math.random()
    };
    this.getNewQuote = this.getNewQuote.bind(this);
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
  }
  
  fetchData() {
    this.setState({isFetching: true});
   fetch ('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json', 
{headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json'
    }})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => 
            {
      this.setState({quotesData: data.quotes, isFetching: false});
      })
    .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.setState({isFetching: false, error: error});
            });
  }
  
  getNewQuote() {
    this.setState({
      random: Math.random()
    });
  } 

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    const {quotesData, isFetching, error} = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (isFetching) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(this.state.random * quotesData.length);
      const nextQuote = quotesData[randomIndex];
      const nextQuoteQuote = nextQuote.quote;
      const nextQuoteAuthor = nextQuote.author;
      return (
      <div id="quote-box">
        <p id="text">{nextQuoteQuote}</p>
        <p id="author">{nextQuoteAuthor}</p>
        <button id="new-quote" onClick={this.getNewQuote}>
          New Quote
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<RandomQuotes />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest fix would be to change `isFetching: true` in the state.
It happens because in the beginning if `isFetching: false` and `error: false` it goes into last `} else {` part where you define

```
const nextQuoteQuote = nextQuote.quote;
const nextQuoteAuthor = nextQuote.author;
```

which are undefined because data is fetching in the background and they are not fetched yet.

So basically when you have to fetch data in the `componentDidMount` method you set loading state to true from the beginning so component knows it has to wait for it to fetch and later on show the data.

Comment: I cannot believe that this has been driving me mad for days and something that simple fixed it, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :) @igorgetmeabrain if you can set my answer as a solution that would be great!